# How to configure Next.js config rewrites between two microfrontends?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-rewrites

I'm trying to organize a microfrontend architecture of two existing Next.js apps. Setup (when asked select app router without src folder, other options irrelevant):

```bash
npx create-next-app@13.5.6 main
npx create-next-app@13.5.6 redirect
```

`redirect/package.json`:

```
"dev": "next dev -p 3001",
```

`main/app/page.tsx`:

```js
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>
        Main
      </h1>
      <Link href="/redirect">
        <h2>
          Redirect
        </h2>
      </Link>
    </main>
  );
}
```

`redirect/app/page.tsx`:

```js
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>
        Redirect
      </h1>
      <Link href="/">
        <h2>
          Main
        </h2>
      </Link>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Maybe add a little bit of styling, to later check that static assets are being served correctly. So I have `main` app listening on port `3000`. When user hits `/redirect` route I want to redirect him to `redirect` app on port `3001`:

`main/next.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        destination: `/:path*`,
      },
      {
        source: "/redirect",
        destination: `http://localhost:3001/redirect`,
      },
      {
        source: "/redirect/:path*",
        destination: `http://localhost:3001/redirect/:path*`,
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And I want `redirect` to be served as `:3000/redirect`, so I add

`redirect/next.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  basePath: "/redirect",
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Now I expect tht click on `redirect` link on main ap page will bring me to redirect app but nothing happens. How to solve this problem?